# Crystal Lang new as a Prefix

Tags: oop, crystal-lang

I was looking at the source code of the crystal compiler, and I came across this:

```
    def self.from(obj : Array)
      case obj.size
      when 0
        Nop.new
      when 1
        obj.first
      else
        new obj
      end
    end
```

In particular, `new obj`. I know that `T.new` is used to create a new instance of type `T`, but I have never seen `new x` before. Is it some sort of method? I didn't see it defined in that file. What is this `new`, and what does it do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably it's just `Something.new(x)`. `new` it's `self.new`, because you can drop `self` inside scope.